# Spring Boot Azure Deployment Unable to Update Code

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I have followed step by step instruction for [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/) document. And it works perfectly fine.

However, I tried changing the return from "Greetings from Spring Boot!" to "Greetings from Spring Boot! v2.0" and made necessary changes (on tests). And then ran `mvn clean package` to remove any existing jar and create a new one and finally ran `./mvnw azure-webapp:deploy` it does update the existing web service. And also states "BUILD Success"

Not sure where am i going wrong.

Comment: If you check the `https://github.com/microsoft/gs-spring-boot/blob/maven/complete/pom.xml` the `<appName>maven-web-app-${maven.build.timestamp}</appName>`, so I think it won't update the existing app, it will always create a new with a different timestamp in the name.

Comment: @hujtomi I have actually set a hardcoded value. Because in future, I will have local MYSQL running on same instance as Java App, as such I require set database config based on the mysql for that instance.

Comment: I went through the tutorial and after changing the `azure-webapp-maven-plugin` version to `<version>1.7.0</version>` it works fine for me. And after changing the code cleaning and deploying again I can see the changes in my WebApp. Maybe if you share your pom.xml it might help to figure out what the problem is in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is the solution - pretty simple. Basically you need to change version under `pom.xml` i.e.

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.1.1</version>
```

update `version` value every time you want to publish. thanks to @hujtomi however you need to do one more thing. i.e. change the value under `web.config` under `httpPlatform`

by default it will point to 0.1.0 version, but you will need to change to 0.1.1 (basically to the version that you want).

In that way, it is actually quite good, so if there are any crashes, you can simply roll back to prev. version.

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar&quot;`

to

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gs-spring-boot-0.1.1.jar&quot;`

Comment: In my comment I was talking about the version of the `azure-webapp-maven-plugin` , but you are talking about the version of the application. I don't think your solution if correct, because even if I don't update the application version before publish, it works fine for me, and it does the update.

Comment: @hujtomi Yes correct. However the best is to update the application version too - as if there any cache or related memories, will also be updated - i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Just as hujtomi said in the comment, every time the maven deploy task will create different web app. Could you please have a check with that?

Comment: Hi, I have. I have actually set to a hardcoded value as I have my SQL settings that requires to be set.